# OpenVPN Download Slow on School Network

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

At my school, I use OpenVPN to access my home network when necessary. When I am not on my VPN, my upload and download speeds both cap at about 30Mbps on average. When I am OpenVPN however, things get a little strange. My average download speed drops to about 5Mbps, and my average upload speed stays at about 20Mbps. What's going on here? Normally, I would think that my school is throttling OpenVPN traffic, but the fact the only my download speeds are slow while my upload speeds remain decent, I am wondering if perhaps something else is causing the problem. My OpenVPN server operates on UDP 1194 from a Raspberry Pi. I have heard some suggest that the Raspberry Pi is the problem, but I do not believe it is because I have been able to use the VPN on other networks, including my own for testing purposes, without any performance issues whatsoever.

Here is my OpenVPN server's configuration file.

```
port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key # This file should be kept secret

dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

client-to-client

keepalive 10 120

comp-lzo

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

log /var/log/openvpn.log

verb 2

mute 10

crl-verify /etc/openvpn/keys/crl.pem
```

**Update:** It has been suggested that the problem I am having could be caused by a slow upload speed on my home network. Here is the result of a speed test, which suggests that this could not be the problem. On top of this, I have been able to use the VPN at higher speeds on other networks, so I do not believe the Raspberry Pi is at fault.

[image: Home Network Speed Test Results]

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have 5 Mbps upload speed at home, so logically you have 5Mbps download speed *from* your home network (minus some VPN overhead) at the max.

If connections to your home network are significantly faster *without* VPN, then your RasPi simply can't handle the traffic any faster.

Comment: I made the mistake of not attaching a speed test of my home network to the question, so I've added it now. I am also certain that the Raspberry Pi is not responsible because I've been able to use the VPN on other networks with no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I bet its caused because all your traffic has to travel trough raspberry which as seen isnt optimal path.
It seems that your school has better connection and route trough raspberry is just detour.

Comment: I've been able to use the VPN on other networks without a problem though.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)